# Isomorphism of schemes and invertible sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, schemes

I have a question more about terminology than anything else:  If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism of schemes, then what does it mean to say "the invertible sheaf $\mathscr{L}$ on $X$ corresponds to the invertible sheaf $\mathscr{M}$ on $Y$?"  Naturally, it makes sense to assume that this statement means $f_{\ast}\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{M}$ or $\mathscr{L}=f^{\ast}\mathscr{M}$, but I wasn't sure...

Comment: Are you sure that it makes a difference, *given that $f$ is an isomorphism*?

Comment: If $f$ is an isomorphism, then there shouldn't be any problem in interpreting this statement as long as you believe that the concept of a sheaf on a scheme is well-defined at all.